# Importing module test data into python tests without explicitly setting PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python

I am trying to import a file (module) that contains test data into my python tests. I am keeping the data separate as it is a large python dictionary and the tests will be mmore readable with them in a separate place.

My test folder:

```
source/
tests/
    elasticsearch_tests/
        fixture_data.py
        test_search.py
        __init__.py
```

I run the tests with:

```
PYTHONPATH=./source python -m unittest discover -s tests
```

In `test_search.py` I attempt to import the data from `fixture_data.py` with:

```
from fixture_data import EVENT_DATA
```

It looks like `fixture_data` is not available on the path as it gives this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fixture_data'
```

I can explicitly add the test folder to the python path and then the data is found and tests work with:

```
PYTHONPATH=./source:./tests/elasticsearch_tests python -m unittest discover -s tests
```

Is there a better way though - in which the tests will automatically pickup the test data module?

Comment: Have you tried `from .fixture_data import EVENT_DATA` ?

Comment: I did not. It works. I did not want to use relative imports - do you think it is alright in this situation?

Comment: I personally don't see an issue using relative imports in your case.